# Mongo query to java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

Currently Mongo Java Driver 3.6.3 supports POJO mapping
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/bson/pojos/
which reduce amount of boilerplate code that needs to be written
It is a great improvement for running native mongo queries
However there is still one thing that needs to be done in my opinion

EASIER native mongo queries construction in java
Example not that complicated query can look like this:

```
List<Document > pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
BasicDbList list = new BasicDbList();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);

Document match = new Document()
    .append("$match", new Document()
        .append("something",
            new Document().append("$in", list))
    );

BasicDBList someFlagParams = new BasicDBList();
fieldConditionSum.add("$some_flag");
fieldConditionSum.add(1);
fieldConditionSum.add(0);

BasicDBList secondFlagParams = new BasicDBList();
fieldConditionSum.add("$other_flag");
fieldConditionSum.add(1);
fieldConditionSum.add(0);

Document group = new Document()
    .append(GROUP, new Document()
        .append("_id", "$some_column")
        .append("some_flag", new Document()
            .append("$sum, new Document()
                .append("$cond", someFlagParams)
            ))
        .append("other_flag", new Document()
            .append("$sum", new Document()
                .append("$cond", otherFlagParams)
            ))
    );

pipeline.add(match);
pipeline.add(group);
```

As you see it is possible to do however it is a bit painful...
For this problem I would see two possible solutions:
**1. Console open source tool** 
I would like to have a tool with such API for example:

```
queryconverter -lang java -input file_with_native_mongo_queries.txt -output java_queries.txt
```

that would generate native mongo query representation in chosen language

**2. Some kind of Mongo Query Util that will prepare org.bson.Document for me**
I just want to prepare native mongo query as a string and pass needed named parameters
I would like to have something like that:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("example_collection");
String stringQuery = "{ ... some complicated query ...  :paramA ......:paramB ...};
MongoQueryParams params = new MongoQueryParams();
params.add("paramA", 100);
params.add("paramB", "something");

Document docQuery = MongoQueryConverter.generate(stringQuery, params);
List<POJO> myPojos = collection.find(docQuery, POJO.class).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

With such solution world would be beautiful :) 
- easy wheezy POJO mapping
- easy wheezy native mongo query creation in java

Maybe I am missing something, 
Are there any kind of similar solution for this problem already?

For the clarification:
- I ONLY want to run native mongo queries
- I do not want to use any kind of ORMs
- I do not want to use Jongo because I see that it is not actively maintained
and I dont want to use other POJO mapping than natively supported by Mongo Java Driver
which is actively maintained

Comment: Although it wil not magically translate your query expressions into MongoDB Java driver code, the [Aggregates](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc?com/mongodb/client/model/Aggregates.html) class would make your client side code much more concise.

Comment: What is your aversion to ORMs?

Comment: Why I hate ORMs? In short: ORMS do not give you a full control what kind of queries will be run on database side, ORMS can create terribly slow queries. There are many articles why using ORMs is antipattern. Please read for example this article of really smart guy Brett Woolridge. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/SansOrm/wiki/ORM-is-an-anti-pattern. It is about SQL ORM but the meaning is the same for other database engines